# Error on IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Trying this IntelliJ IDE first time. I just created a Hello World one line Java program (from template included with IDE) and IDE is giving error.

> Error:Module 'Hello World' production: java.net.URISyntaxException:
>   Illegal character in path at index 61:
>   file://C:/Users/Home/Programming/Workspace/IdeaProjects/Hello World

Same program in eclipse is running fine.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Framework: JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space from "Hello World" folder name.
You can rename it to "Hello_World"